# TYPO3 own extension using RTE

Tags: typo3, rte

Im writing my own extension. Now i like my textarea to be edited i RTE. I tried some configurations from web and i cannot make it work..

Part of my TCA:

```
    'tasks' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:jobs/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_jobs_domain_model_joboffer.tasks',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 15
        ),
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext[]'

    ),
```

Like here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Rte/InTheBackend/Index.html
NOT WORKING :(

I also tried similar to this: http://typo3blogger.de/der-t3editor-im-tca/ and also cannot make it work. In cms i always see simple textarea. Any ideas how to plug it in?

my TCA script:

```
'types' => array(
    '1' => array('showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1, add_date, reference_number, position, link_url, localization, title, requirements;;;richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_links], tasks;;;richtext::rte_transform[flag=rte_disabled|mode=ts_css], offer;;;richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_links], category, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'),
),
```

and columns:

```
'tasks' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:jobs/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_jobs_domain_model_joboffer.tasks',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 15
        ),
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext[]'

    ),
```

Comment: Which version of TYPO3?

Answer (score 1):

If you field is called *tasks*, you need in your *showitem** section this code:

`tasks;;;richtext::rte_transform[flag=rte_disabled|mode=ts_css],`

see e.g. https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_news.php#L612

Comment: I have tried it but no change.. i post below whole file.